# I'm new to Java. I coded a Java program that adds two numbers. Can't get to display the sum as int.

Tags: java

Hi I'm totally new to the Java language and my professor gave us an assignment that's not too complicated. I've done most of it correctly. Here's what we're supposed to do. If you enter two integers the sum should be an int. If you enter two doubles the sum should be a double. And if either of the two is a double then also the sum should be a double. And if either of the two can be interepreted as a Binary number, it should be treated as such. Lastly, if both numbers are Binary then the sum should be displayed in binary. The code I have so far, does everything except when I enter two ints it gives me the sum as a double, can somebody please suggest where I should make a change to fix that?

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProjectZero 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
        cin.useRadix(2);

        System.out.print("Enter two numbers separated by a space: ");

        if (cin.hasNextInt()) 
        {
            int first = cin.nextInt();

            if (cin.hasNextInt()) 
            {
                int second = cin.nextInt();
                bigFunction(first, second);
            } 
            else if (cin.hasNextDouble()) 
            {
                double second = cin.nextDouble();
                bigFunction(first,second);
            } 
            else 
                System.out.println("Please try again and enter numbers.");
        } 
        else if (cin.hasNextDouble()) 
        {
            double first = cin.nextDouble();

            if (cin.hasNextDouble()) 
            {
                double second = cin.nextDouble();
                bigFunction(first,second);
            } 
            else 
                System.out.println("Please try again and enter numbers.");
        } 
        else 
            System.out.println("Please try again and enter numbers.");

        cin.close();    
    }

    public static void bigFunction(int a, int b) 
    {
        int sum = a + b;
        System.out.print("The sum of " + Integer.toBinaryString(a) + " (Decimal value: " + a + ")");
        System.out.println(" and " + Integer.toBinaryString(b) + " (Decimal value: " + b  + ")" + " is " + Integer.toBinaryString(sum));
    }

    public static void bigFunction(double a, double b) 
    {
        double sum = a + b; 
        System.out.println("The sum of " + a + " and " + b + " is " + sum);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

even easier answer do

instead of if .hasNextDouble

```
if (first % 1 ==0)
{
//you have an integer
}
else
{
//it is not an integer
}
```

the % means modulus which basically divides something and check if there is a remainder if there is a remainder after deviding a number by 1 it is not an int

Comment: always pass the values to BigFunction as doubles and run the code above inside that

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to read the two inputs as Strings. Then check the strings to see whether they contain only the digits 0 and 1 (if so, binary number). If not binary, check whether it can be interpreted as a double. If so, cast to int and see if it is the same value (then it is an int). If it can't be read as a double, it is bad format. Note that you might have to consider if the number is too big to fit an int, or long, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting the sum as double when both the input's are int is because you are changing the default radix of scanner, hence it fails to recognize the input as int and instead reads it as a double.

If you don't change the radix of scanner, it will use the default radix (10) and scan input at base 10. Now this will work for input: int & double; but will not work for binary input's. All this boils down to your choice of implementation and I don't think you can accomodate all the required inputs with your current approach. I'd suggest following @FredK approach and take the input as string (even that approach has it's own flaws).

Comment: I see what you're saying, but If I don't use the radix (2), I won't be able to identify Binary numbers (which is a requirement) :(

Comment: I understand, but setting the radix has it's own limitation. You can ask the user what sort of input they will be providing, and based on that you can accept the input.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way for you to check if the two numbers entered are in fact two separate ints.  And also, you are asking for two double parameters and your sum is also a double so when you put the ints into the `bigFunction`, you are always casting them to doubles and the sum is a double so you will always get a double.

You need to have a check inside the `bigFunction` function to check if they are in fact two doubles or two ints, etc.

Or in fact make separate functions, but always strive for laziness!

Hope that gets the gears churning!

Comment: Of course it IS possible to determine if the two numbers entered are ints.

Comment: I did not mean it as if there is "NO" way to check, I'm saying in his particular implementation that he showed to us, there is no way to be able to determine if they are in fact ints, etc. because he did not implement such code.

Answer (score -2):

In java an integer is a form of double if you run the code

```
int a =4
int b =5
double b = a +c
System.out.print(b);
```

this would work as an integer is a form of double.

the easiest way would be to rename your double method to something else

best solution

userinput (the double) = variable

```
if ((variable == Math.floor(variable))
```

this rounds the number do so 5.9 would be 5 and if the that is equal to variable you have an int.